# XBee data from sensor to Arduino Mega 2560 is not changing+wrong

Tags: arduino, xbee

I am trying to get a sensor value through [XBee](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XBee) S2 to another XBee S2 that is connected to an [Arduino Mega 2560](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/arduinoBoardMega2560) and send the data to a web service. In this code I am sending a constant data (10, 0, 0), but I want to send sensor data which I can`t get right till now. This is the code:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial gprsSerial(7, 8);
SoftwareSerial xbee(0, 1);

unsigned long int avgValue; //Store the average value of the sensor feedback
float b;
int buf[10], temp;

void setup() {
  gprsSerial.begin(9600);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  xbee.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("Config SIM900...");
  delay(2000);
  Serial.println("Done!...");
  gprsSerial.flush(); //Waits for the transmission of outgoing serial data to complete.

  // Attach or detach from GPRS service
  gprsSerial.println("AT+CGATT=1");
  delay(100);
  toSerial();


  // Bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"CONTYPE\",\"GPRS\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // Bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=3,1,\"APN\",\"zain\"");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();

  // bearer settings
  gprsSerial.println("AT+SAPBR=1,1");
  delay(2000);
  toSerial();
};

void loop() {
  if (xbee.available() >= 0) {
    for (int i = 1; i < 19; i++) {
      byte discardByte = xbee.read();
    }

    int analogMSB = xbee.read();
    int analogLSB = xbee.read();
    int analogReading = analogLSB + (analogMSB * 256);
    float phValue=(float)analogReading * 5.0 / 1024 / 6; //Convert the analog into millivolt
    phValue=-35.3*phValue;                               //Convert the millivolt into pH value
    Serial.print("    pH:");
    Serial.print(phValue,2);
    Serial.println(" ");

    // Initialize HTTP service
    gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPINIT");
    delay(2000);
    toSerial();

    // Set HTTP parameter value
    gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPPARA= \"URL\" ,\"http://ar.ahu.edu.jo/sensor.aspx?Sens1=10&Sens2=0&Sens3=0\"");
    delay(2000);
    toSerial();

    // Set HTTP action type 0 = GET, 1 = POST, 2 = HEAD
    gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPACTION=0");
    delay(6000);
    toSerial();

    // Read server response
    gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPREAD");
    delay(1000);
    toSerial();

    gprsSerial.println("");
    gprsSerial.println("AT+HTTPTERM");
    toSerial();
    delay(300);

    gprsSerial.println("");
    delay(10000);
  }
}

void toSerial()
{
  while(gprsSerial.available()!=0)
  {
    Serial.println(gprsSerial.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: What debugging have you done?  Can you print the characters you're receiving from the XBee?  Is this the code from the sending end or receiving end?  What parts work and what parts don't work?  In the code you posted, you're discarding bytes without looking for the start of frame (`0x7E`), frame length, frame type or frame checksum.  Once you're reading valid values, it will be easy to modify the `println()` to use formatting characters (`%d` for `int` and `%f` for `float`) and the necessary parameters (like `phValue`).

Comment: i think that is the problem about the frame. when i add an if clause to search for the start of the frame (0x7E) or frame length to be 21 it just doesnt work and nothing is even printed on the serial monitor except "config sim900" and "done"
mr @tomlogic please help me to the end my university graduation depend on this

Comment: Try to buffer the receiving frame in an array and let the `start of frame 0x7E` , `frame length` and `frame type` be useful for you.